# Multiple select query in .net for a dataset

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

can i write somthing like this:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from cmn_mst; select * from cmn_typ", oledbCon);
```

But this is showing an error. Is there any other way to write multiple select in dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a stored procedure, that outputs 2 ref cursors and call it in your .net code.

a detailed answer would need a knowledge in the type of provider your using.

But this should help google stuff.

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322160) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in one OleDbCommand, you need to split the queries in two commands, so 2 datasets..

Comment: suppose when i write like `new OleDbCommand("sp_cmn_mst", oledbCon);` and sp_cm_mst is a storeprocedure returning 2 table.. then the dataset is containing 2 table data...

Comment: Ok, what is ther problem with that? You can access the two Datatables of the Dataset as easily as the Dataset itself.

Comment: i just wanted to make smaller in code... but from the above answers i got it is better to use SP

Answer (score 1):

What is your reason of putting 2 queries in one dataset?

If you want to make it smaller in code, you may use views or stored procedure in you database.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Try making this in two commands.

```
DataSet set1 = new DataSet();
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from cmn_mst;", connection))
{
   adapter.Fill(set1);
}

DataSet set2 = new DataSet();
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from cmn_typ;", connection))
{
   adapter.Fill(set2);
}
```

After Returning Two Dataset You can merge it into once

```
set1.EnforceConstraints = false;
set1.Merge(set2, true, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
set1.EnforceConstraints = true;
set1.AcceptChanges();
```

For further reference:

- [Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/how-to-join-two-datatables-using-c-no-database-access?forum=adodotnetdataset)

**Method 2:**

- You have to write Stored Procedure and call it in your code.